# SPAlert.Filter not working

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Can anybody help with SPAlert filters on Sharepoint 2013?

If I set Filter property on SPAlert instance  the alert has not been sent

```
SPAlert newAlert = user.Alerts.Add();

SPAlertTemplateCollection alertTemplates = new SPAlertTemplateCollection(
(SPWebService)(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Parent));

newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
newAlert.List = list;
newAlert.Title = alertTitle;
newAlert.DeliveryChannels = SPAlertDeliveryChannels.Email;
newAlert.EventType = eventType;
newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
newAlert.AlertTemplate = alertTemplates[Constants.AlertTemplates.GenericListCustom];                            

var wsm = new WorkflowServicesManager(web);
var wss = wsm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var subscriptions = wss.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(list.ID);
bool assotiationExist = false;
var guid = Constants.Workflows.ApprovalWF.Guid;
foreach (var subs in subscriptions)
{
    assotiationExist = subs.DefinitionId == guid;
        if (assotiationExist)
        {
               newAlert.Filter = "<Query><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ApprovalStatus\"/><Value type=\"string\">Approved</Value></Eq></Query>";
        }
}                               

newAlert.Update(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in line newAlert.EventType = eventType. eventType was SPEventType.Add. That was the reason of not sending alert after Workflow set the ApprovalStatus field to «Approved».

I’ve modified algourithm. Now eventType is SPEventType.Modify and I added new field "IsNewAlertSent" to list. When event fires the first time then I send email and set the "IsNewAlertSent" field

Final code is shown below.

class UserAlertManager:

```
..
newAlert.EventType = (eventType == SPEventType.Add? SPEventType.Modify: eventType);
newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
newAlert.AlertTemplate = alertTemplates[Constants.AlertTemplates.GenericListCustom];
..
           if (assotiationExist)
           {
              newAlert.Filter = "<Query><Eq><FieldRef name=\"ApprovalStatus\"/><Value type=\"Text\">Approved</Value></Eq></Query>";
              newAlert.Properties.Add("grcustomalert", "1"); 

            }
..
newAlert.Update(false);
```

class GRCustomAlertHandler:

```
...
string subject = string.Empty;
string body = string.Empty;
bool grCustomAlert = Utils.IsSPAlertCustom(ahp.a);
if (ahp.eventData[0].eventType == (int)SPEventType.Modify && grCustomAlert)
{
             SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(ahp.eventData[0].itemId);
             var isNewAlertSentField = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(Constants.Fields.IsNewAlertSent);
             if (isNewAlertSentField != null && (item[Constants.Fields.IsNewAlertSent] == null || !(bool)item[Constants.Fields.IsNewAlertSent]))
             {
                       ...                           
                        Utils.SendMail(web, new List<string> { ahp.headers["to"].ToString() }, subject, body);
                               item[Constants.Fields.IsNewAlertSent] = true;
                                using (new DisabledItemEventScope())
                                {
                                    item.SystemUpdate(false);
                                }
                }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I set Filter property on SPAlert instance the alert has not been sent

What do you need exactly ?

If you just want to change the filter (alert condition), did you simply try :

```
newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
newAlert.List = list;
newAlert.Title = alertTitle;
newAlert.DeliveryChannels = SPAlertDeliveryChannels.Email;
newAlert.EventType = eventType;
newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
newAlert.AlertTemplate = alertTemplates[Constants.AlertTemplates.GenericListCustom];
newAlert.Filter = "<Query><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ApprovalStatus/New\"/><Value type=\"string\">Approved</Value></Eq></Query>";
newAlert.Update(false);
```

I have just added a /New in your filter query. Query filter in alert need to get a /New or a /Old in your field.

If your alert still doesn't work, it might be something else than the filter.